# Add controls into textblock wpf in code behind

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can i convert this UI into code behind wpf

```html
<TextBlock x:Name="tblImgCorrectAnswer">
  <Span>Hello</Span>
  <Span Style="{DynamicResource FontMSMincho}">て</Span>
  <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock>
      <Image Source="Images/icon.ico" Width="40" Height="40"/>
    </TextBlock>
  </InlineUIContainer>

</TextBlock>
```

I cann't anyway to add item control into textblock control or TextBlock control into InlineUIContainer control by using code-behind.

Thanhks.

The result like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnNcI.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Behind**

```
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        var inlineHello = new Span();
        inlineHello.Inlines.Add("Hello");
        var inlineJSighn = new Span();
        inlineJSighn.Inlines.Add(" JSighn");
        BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
        logo.BeginInit();
        logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Koala.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
        logo.EndInit();
        var inlineUiContainer = new InlineUIContainer(new Image { Source = logo });
        inlineUiContainer.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center;
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(inlineHello);
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(inlineJSighn);
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(inlineUiContainer);


        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="AddChildrenToGrinInCode.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/></Window>
```

Comment: @AnthonyHung than you, and feel free to mark your question as answered if the answer helped you.